# time complexity of this while loop

Tags: java, time-complexity

Hi
I have written such a this code and I want to know that : its time complexity is O(n) ?

```
      DNode header = new DNode(null, null, null);
        DNode trailer = new DNode(null, header, null);
        header.next = trailer;
        for (Point point : pointList) {
            DNode node = new DNode(point, header, trailer);
            dList.addLast(node);
            header = node;
        }
```

I want to copying all objects from the `pointList(ArrayList)` to a `dList(Doubly-Linked list)`.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There's only one obvious loop here, which is O(n) - and everything within the loop is O(1), assuming a sensible implementation of the doubly-linked list.

Comment: I have a problem that adding a list to the end of the doubly linked list in such a way has O(n) or O(1)?

Comment: @user472221: Well you haven't told us what implementation you're using, but generally speaking a doubly-linked list has O(1) time for insertion at either end. If you're using `LinkedList<T>` from the JDK, that's certainly true.

Comment: public void addLast(DNode v) {
        addBefore(trailer, v);
    }

Comment: @user472221: Well what does `addBefore` do?

Comment: public void addBefore(DNode v, DNode z) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        DNode u = v.getPrev();// may throw an IllegalArgumentException!!
        z.setPrev(u);
        z.setNext(v);
        u.setNext(z);
        v.setPrev(z);
        size++;
    }

Comment: @user472221: Well that just goes into more methods. Do you see the problem here? Any of those methods that you haven't told us about before could do something nasty, like finding its current index in the list. It's very unlikely to, but currently your question is sort of equivalent to "What number am I thinking of?"